# Outputting internal at-macro via newcommand?

Tags: macros

Just noticed a somewhat strange behavior, when trying to show [internal Latex @ commands](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-atsigns) from main document via `\newcommand`.

Consider the following MWE, where all instances of the internal macro ( `\c@something`) calls are already wrapped in `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}


% define internal at-macro
\makeatletter
\def\c@something{AAA}
\typeout{ == \c@something == }
\makeatother

% define a newcommand calling the at-macro
\newcommand{\mytest}{
\makeatletter
\c@something
\makeatother
}



\begin{document}


test

\mytest{}

\makeatletter
here \c@something
\makeatother


\end{document}
```

When I build the above with `pdflatex`, I get this:

[image: test.png]

... however, I would have expected something like:

```
test
AAA
here AAA
```

Can anyone explain why does the macro not get called/executed when put as part of `\newcommand` - and else looks ok called directly from the main body? (In other words, could I get its output as part of `\newcommand` at all?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TeX converts characters to tokens when it first reads them. So when you do

```
\newcommand{\mytest}{
\makeatletter
\c@something
\makeatother
}
```

TeX 'sees' `@` as an 'other' character, and the definition of `\mytest` is:

1. A space (as you have a new line with no `%` just after the opening `{`)
2. The token `\makeatletter`
3. The token `\c`
4. The 'other' character `@`
5. The 'letter' tokens 'something' (each separate)
6. The token `\makeatother`

What you wanted was

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mytest}{%
  \c@somecommand
}
\makeatother
```

in which case the definition of `\mytest` is the single token `\c@somecommand`, exactly as for the `\def` case.

Comment: Awesome - many, many thanks for that, @JosephWright! Special thanks for breaking it down character by character - it also cleared up other things for me (_such as the comment before the end of line thing `:)`_) ; cheers!